# How to use Layout Params in RecyclerView Item

Tags: java, android

I have app about surveys. I list all active surveys in `RecyclerView`.

In the bottom of `RecyclerView custom item`, I add profile pictures of users who attendant to that survey (like in facebook - seen by bla bla)

I decided to implement imageview to that layout horizontally with params, somehow i couldn't and images are not displaying on item.

Here is my `OnBindViewHolder`(Other parts work well)

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(surveyList.get(position).getItem_image())
            .into(holder.item_survey_image);

    String imageStringList = surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_users_image();
    List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(imageStringList.split(","));

    for(int i=0; i<splitList.size(); i++){

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(splitList.get(i))
                .into(holder.item_survey_users_image);


        if (holder.item_survey_users_image.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) holder.item_survey_users_image.getParent()).removeView(holder.item_survey_users_image);


       holder.item_layout_users.addView(holder.item_survey_users_image, layoutParams);
    }

    holder.item_survey_head.setText(surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_head());
    holder.item_survey_desc.setText(surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_desc());
    holder.item_survey_amount.setText(surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_amount());
    holder.item_survey_time.setText(surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_time());
    holder.item_survey_users.setText(surveyList.get(position).getItem_survey_users());

    holder.item_cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how you can tell the picture absence is caused by layoutparams ? however here is how you implement a layoutParams in your OnBindViewHolder, say you have RelativeLayout

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params`
`=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,`
`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`
       `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);`
      `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`
       `params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //if you need margins`
        `holder.item_survey_image.setLayoutParams(params);`